# How can I control Json.NET serilaization to use a custom version of JsonIgnore?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Having just merged two branches of a class library, I find one has added several `JsonIgnore` attributes to model properties. These will break the web client of that library, but are required in the mobile client of that library. I would like to create a new 'Json ignore' attribute that will only ignore marked properties if the calling code is not the web client. Then I would like to hook into the serialization code to look at my new attribute vs. the normal one.

Comment: Unfortunately JsonIgnoreAttribute is both sealed and used as a simple marker. It'll clutter your model classes but AFAIK way to go is using preprocessor directives (and having two build: mobile and web).

Answer (score 1):

Not a good idea. My suggestion is the classes(let's call them models) in the shared project are really shared (with no attributes), and in other projects where the models are outputted you define classes with attributes. Something like this:

```
//in MyProject.Core which is shared
class User
{
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public string UserName { get; set; }
     public string Password { get; set; }
}

//in MyProject.WcfApi which has wcf services for other teams
[DataContract]
class UserOutput
{
     [DataMember]
     public int Id { get; set; }
     [DataMember]
     public string UserName { get; set; }
     //no password property here
}

//in MyProject.WebApi which has some web apis for js
class UserOutput
{
    [MyJsonRelatedAttribute]
    public int Id { get; set; }    
}
```

Comment: That would be ideal, I like it, but practicalities right now prevent me from implementing a wider ranging change like this. :-(